# Ec261 compensation : European Flight of less than 3000km, delayed by 9 hours. Is compensation limited to €400?

Tags: compensation, ec261

My flight from Tenerife south to Gatwick had to make an emergency landing due to technical issues in Porto Santo. We were delayed getting back to Gatwick by 9 hours (finally landing at 00:30, thereby incurring an £80 taxi fare home) whilst waiting on a replacement plane to collect us. The airline initially tried to deny me compensation erroneously claiming I was "a member of staff".

Now they are saying as the flight is less than 3500 km I can only receive €400 regardless of the 9 hour time delay. Is this correct or should I receive €600?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are correct.

This chart shows how much compensation you can claim:

> [image]

([image source](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#compensation-delay-1))

The distance from London to Tenerife is under 3000 km, around 2900 km. Therefore you can claim €400 even for a 9 hour delay.

Comment: Don't forget the limit applies to compensation only.  Reasonable costs incurred, which the airline must also meet, are not part of that.

Comment: @MadHatter yes, by *reasonable costs* do you mean the taxi fare etc.?

Comment: I did, but I'm struggling to find a reference.  Costs due to delayed *departure* are [supposed to be met](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#care-delay-1), but I'm not yet so sure about delayed *arrival*.  Sorry, my bad.

Comment: (+1) @MadHatter Case law extended these rights and I think a case could be made that article 9 assistance (refreshment, phone calls, even hotel rooms if the situation had lasted longer) should have been provided at Porto Santo even if the departure was on time. The problem with the OP's taxi ride is that it occurred after they finally reached their destination. Missed long-distance trains or expensive cruises do not fall within the scope of this “right to assistance” either.

Comment: @Relaxed feel free to post pointers to case law regarding that last sentence.  I, for one, would find them *most* useful.

Comment: @MadHatter There is a lot and it's always moving so I struggle to follow it precisely. That's why I tried to phrase my earlier comment somewhat guardedly. I just found [this earlier answer of mine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72856/under-eu-rules-can-i-receive-compensation-if-my-flight-was-delayed-by-more-than/72861#72861) that cited some important decisions but those were related to compensation, not assistance. You would need to study the exact reasoning used by the court and more recent decisions to find out more.

Comment: @Relaxed no, I wouldn't: I'm the one who said I was struggling to find a reference.  You came along over a year later and suggested that you had more definitive information, so I invited you to post it.  If what you meant is "*I, too, don't have any good references one way or another*", that's interesting to hear, but it doesn't seem to me to be quite what you said.

Comment: @MadHatter I gave you (and anyone who cares) additional info (namely that the time of arrival does matter, not because of the letter of the regulation but because of the way the court extended it) and very specific references (case numbers, read my answer), exactly what you said you were struggling to find. The bit I was unsure about (whether assistance should have been provided during an unplanned stop) was prefaced with "I think". Why the hostility?

Comment: @Relaxed because you're suggesting the responsibility to go and research the issue is mine ("*You would need to study...*").  I was happy with my position, and understood - and admitted - that it had grey areas and might well be wrong.  I'm perfectly happy - indeed, ecstatic - to have it updated with *better information*, but to have someone else wander along with an alternative opinion and then suggest that it's my responsibility, not theirs, to do the legwork is mildly annoying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128644/discussion-between-relaxed-and-madhatter).